# How to retrieve query string from Microsoft Bot Framework Composer

Tags: botframework

[Microsoft Bot Framework Composer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/introduction) provides a visual way design and publish a chat bot to Azure.  Azure's [bot channel registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) provides a way to allow you to embed the bot into a web page using iframe. The HTML snippet looks like this:

<iframe src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/mybot?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE' style='min-width: 400px; width: 100%; min-height: 500px;'>

This works fine. However, I want to pass to the bot another piece of information so I know about the customer chatting with the bot without asking them.  So, if I add to the URL "&userId=USER_ID", the bot still works fine, but I just don't know how to retrieve this piece of information from the bot when designing it using the [Microsoft Bot Framework Composer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/). I can't find anything in their [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/) either. Anyone knows how?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add additional channel data to the activities sent to your bot, I would recommend using the CDN instead of the embedded version of Web Chat. Take a look at the [Piggyback Data on Every Outgoing Activity](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/b.piggyback-on-outgoing-activities) Web Chat Sample for details on how to get started.

Comment: That won't work.  My use case is:  I don't own the website.  I give my bot link to my client and they put it on their page.  When their user clicks on some link, it loads my bot.  At this point, I need to know the user's Name and ID, so that the bot can greet the user by name, and store the conversation with the user ID.  My client will, at a later time, make a call to my API with the user ID, to get the processed data.  I was hoping that the Name and ID can be passed with the iframe link.  Eg:  <iframe src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/mybot?s=SECRET&Name=John&UID=1234' class='bot'>

Comment: I apologize - I miss read your question. You can use `turn.activity.from.id` to retrieve the user id you set in the URL.

Comment: I think you missed my last comment as well, but it is my fault.  Stackoverflow truncated my iframe tag right after embed/  so I think you missed the context.   I am not sure how to show you the whole tag without it being truncated.  So, here is the encoded iframe tag:  **%3Ciframe%20src%3D%27https%3A%2F%2Fwebchat.botframework.com%2Fembed%2Fmybot%3Fs%3DSECRET%26Name%3DJohn%26UID%3D1234%27%20class%3D%27bot%27%20%2F%3E** (Please do Url decode to see).  I need to retrieve the values for Name and UID passed in the src value of the iframe.

Comment: `turn.activity.from.id` should retrieve the id, and `turn.activity.from.name` should be the user name you provided in the url.